# Investpy: pass the stocks code and receive the ISIN in the return

Tags: python

I recently discovered the investpy library and I would like to know if there is any function where I can pass the stocks code and on return, among other data, receive its ISIN. I'm trying the function`search_quotes`, but the ISIN doesn't come back.

```
import investpy as ip
search = ip.search_quotes(text='CPLE11')
for s in search:
    print(s)
```

If anyone knows of any other library where I can pass the code and receive the ISIN, that helps too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ISIN by symbol as follows:

```
import investpy
symbol = "TSLA"
df = investpy.search_stocks(by='symbol', value=symbol)
df = df[df.symbol == symbol]
print(df)
```

However the code does not work for the symbol you provided. You have to find the correct symbol by mapping it.

EDIT: It might also be the case that this specific company cannot be found using this API. I tried to find it with the following code:

```
stocks = stocks = investpy.stocks.get_stocks()
matches = [_ for idx, _ in stocks.iterrows() if _["name"].startswith("Companhia")]
print([m["name"] for m in matches])
```

Your stock is not among the matches.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the openfigi API
https://www.openfigi.com/api

```
Value   ID_ISIN 
Description
ISIN - International Securities Identification Number.

Example:
[{"idType":"ID_ISIN","idValue":"XX1234567890"}]
```

Comment: I need receive the ISIN.